# Rip-off (an ncurses term) single bottom line out of /dev/tty terminal, is it possible?

Tags: zsh, tty, devices, wrap

`Ncurses` allows to separate a single line from screen, at level of physical screen (`curscr`), to devote it to e.g. a title bar, thus also creating a logical screen (`stdscr`), devoted to application's viewport. It's  the `ncurses` call `ripoffline()` that's responsible for this.

This serves as a basic explanation of my problem – I need to do the same with `/dev/tty`. The best for me would be to create a dummy e.g. `/tmp/tty.LCRiAotf`, which would wrap `/dev/tty` and somehow rip-off the single top or bottom line.

My master-script would use `/dev/tty` and provide the top-or-bottom menu bar I want to create, while say a slave-script would use `/tmp/tty.LCRiAotf` which is a logical tty 1-row less in height, not interfering with the menu bar.

The best would be to do this in shell script, in general in Zshell. I know it might be hard to create a wrapper tty device with command-line tools, but maybe it's possible? Other solutions are also welcomed. Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but too complex for any useful zsh/bash script.  Take a look at tmux and screen.

Answer (score 0):

Dialog(1) and whiptail(1) are command-line programs built on the ncurses library allowing shell-script level creation of pop-up boxes, menus and such like.  I do not know if they cover the specific usage you seek.

Comment: You should [edit] this to describe how these utilities provide a solution for the OP. See [answer].